# HTTPClient Angular

Tags: angular, rest

I'm new to angular6, I've been previously working lot of android projects and i had the Spring and Hibernate setup. Which is working super fine with the Android volley.

Now i'm finding difficult to extract the data from the RestAPI, So the REST api data is :

```
collection  {
  version   : "1.0"
  error : null
  **data    : {
      id    : 1
      name  : "Test"
      password  : "MTIzNDU="
      createdDate : null
      email : "s.puspharaj@gmail.com"
      userArea  : "coimbatore"
      fcmTokenId    : ""
      mobileNo  : 4545456456
      googleAuth    : "yes"
      appVersionCode    : null
      }**
      statusCode    : 200
      booleanStatus : null }
```

How do i extract the above collection data in Angular6?. I'm not sure how to debug like in android in angular. How to save this in User model in angular?

Model class of User:

```
export class User {
id: number;
name: String;
createdDate: Date;
email: String;
userArea: String;
fcmTokenId: String;
mobileNo: String;
googleAuth: String;
appVersionCode: String;
modifyDate: String;
serverTime: String;

get getid() {
    return this.id;
}

set setid(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
}

get getName() {
    return this.name;
}

set setName(name: String) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Model of Collection :

```
export class Collection {
public version: String;
public data: Object;
public error: CollectionError;
public statusCode: number;
public booleanStatus: boolean;

get getError() {
    return this.error;
}

/**
 * @param error the error to set
 */
set setError(error: CollectionError) {
    this.error = error;
}

/**
 * @return the version
 */
get getVersion() {
    return this.version;
}

/**
 * @param version the version to set
 */
set setVersion(version: String) {
    this.version = version;
}

/**
 * @return the data
 */
get getData() {
    return this.data;
}

/**
 * @param data the data to set
 */
set setData(data: Object) {
    this.data = data;
}

get getStatusCode() {
    return this.statusCode;
}

set setStatusCode(statusCode: number) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

get isBooleanStatus() {
    return this.booleanStatus;
}

set setBooleanStatus(booleanStatus: boolean) {
    this.booleanStatus = booleanStatus;
}
```

}

And HTTP Client i tried so far is :

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getUser(): Observable<Collection> {
   return this.http.get<Collection>('http://localhost:8080/tooveWeb/v1/user/1');
}

onClickLogin() {
this.data.getUser().subscribe((collection) => this.collection.user = 
collection.user);
console.log(this.collection);
```

}

How do i extract the **data** and store to model class and present to html?

Please suggest!

Thanks

Comment: After data from Http call has arrived, you get an object of type User but you wouldn't be able to use methods of that class (like getters). Use interfaces instead of classes and create classes afterwards.

Comment: Tried with interface , couldn't extract the data fields

Answer (score 1):

In your `subscription` to `getuser()` method, you can assign the response data to `user` property of `Collection` class

```
private collection : Collection = new Collection() // method 1
```

OR

inject the `Collection` class in your component

```
constructor(private collection : Collection) { }  // method 2

this.getUser.subscribe((coll)=> {      
     this.collection.user= coll.data
})
```

Comment: Above didn't work.. The error i get core.js:1633 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (app.component.ts:29)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__t

Comment: What you mean by didn't work? You should tell also what didn't work. What error are you getting?

Comment: That is because, your object is not yet initialised, You can do `private collection : Collection = new Collection()`

Comment: Instead, you can also inject `Collection` in your component.

Comment: @Amit...thanks for the great reply..Now the collection is empty using     console.log(this.collection); On the console i see only this Collection {user: User}
user
:
undefined
,

Comment: What does `console.log(coll)` prints inside subscribe?

Comment: The above print {collection: {…}, booleanStatus: null}booleanStatus: nullcollection: data: appVersionCode: nullcreatedDate: nullemail: "s.puspharaj@gmail.com"fcmTokenId: ""googleAuth: "yes"id: 1mobileNo: 9994794898modifyDate: nullname: "Test"password: "MTIzNDU="serverTime: nulluserArea: "coimbatore"__proto__: Objecterror: nullstatusCode: 200version: "1.0"__proto__: Object__proto__: Object

Comment: So you have the data returned properly. Print `console.log(this.collection);` inside subscribe after setting `this.collection.user`. You are probably trying to print it outside subscribe block. That is why you get `undefined`. Look through how `asynchronous` methods work.

Comment: I tried to print only the data:{....} objects inside the collection, but failed to do so. But how do i extract the data{...} objects to User model? thanks for the immense support.

Answer (score 0):

> How to save this in User model in angular?

You need to subscribe when you call the `getUser`. Inside the subscription you can assing the response value to the user models.

```
private collection : Collection;

this.getUser.subscribe((coll)=> {      
     this.collection.user= coll.data
})
```

> How do i extract the above collection data in Angular6?.

You can access the user object using `this.collection.user`

> I'm not sure how to debug like in android in angular

You can set breakpoints using `debugger`. And using browser developer tools (right click --> inspect).

Or you can use `console.logs`

Read this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_debugging.asp) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Http is asynchronous. That means with this code:

```
onClickLogin() {
  this.data.getUser().subscribe((collection) => this.collection.user = 
  collection.user);
  console.log(this.collection); //// <-- ALWAYS UNDEFINED!!
}
```

If you want to see your values, you need to move your logging within the subscribe as shown below:

```
onClickLogin() {
  this.data.getUser().subscribe((collection) => {
  this.collection.user = collection.user;
  console.log(this.collection); // <-- here instead
  });
}
```

next if you want to use `collection` in your template (html) you can use `async` pipe , [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51394424/angular-2-display-value-from-observable/51394898#51394898)