# Angular 2 Display value from Observable

Tags: angular, observable

Hi I want display my value from response http but I don't know what is the problem.

http :

```
getAllApiContext(){
     const options = this.getOptions("...");
    return this.http
        .get("jenkins/job/api_initialization/api/json", options)
        .map((data: any) => {
            return data.json().property[0].parameterDefinitions[1].choices;
        })
}
```

She return array.

My component.ts

```
context: Observable<Array<any>>;
ngOnInit() {
  this.jenkinsJob.getAllApiContext().subscribe(data => {
    this.context = data;
  });
};
```

My component.html

```
 <span *ngFor="let item of context | async">
   <p>{{item}}</p>
 </span>
```

Comment: What is the error or current behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the async in the `ngFor`. since you are already subscribing to the observable, no need to use the async pipe

```
<span *ngFor="let item of context">
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `async` pipe you don't need to subscribe

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.context = this.jenkinsJob.getAllApiContext();
};
```

[AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)